# How to convert Java datetime code to Python

Tags: java, python-2.7

I have a snippet of Java code I need to convert to Python see below:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz");
sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
String date = sdf.format(new Date());
```

Ok the final code to achieve this is:

```
 import datetime
 from pytz import timezone 

 now = datetime.datetime.now()
 gmt_time = now.replace(tzinfo=timezone('GMT'))
 date=gmt_time.strftime("%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %Z")
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: Sorry I added example code, I didnt do this when I clicked the add question. My mistake I have added the code so far.

Comment: `datetime.now` takes an optional timezone: https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.now

Comment: As an aside, in Java you should not have used the `SimpleDateFormat` class. It is long outdated and notoriously troublesome. Instead use `OffsetDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC).format(DateTimeFormatter.RFC_1123_DATE_TIME)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to install `pytz` (a World Timezone Definitions package) on your system.

Try this :

```
from datetime import datetime
from pytz import timezone 

now = datatime.datetime.now();
gmt_time = now.replace(tzinfo=timezone('GMT'))
print(gmt_time.strftime("%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z"))
```

**I have referred from here (this includes the installation process) : http://pytz.sourceforge.net/#tzinfo-api**

Comment: Thanks this more or less got me there, there we some modifications I needed to do to make this work however. datetime.now had to be datetime.datetime.now and the %z needed to be %Z to print GMT instead of +0000 etc. But awesome help thanks. I have updated the main question with the working code.

Comment: Can you just give a tick as a verified answer ?

Comment: If it has helped you in getting what you want. :)